# Windows-app to quickly enter iptc keywords

Tags: metadata, tagging

I have scanned thousands of slides. They have no metadata.

Is there a windows application to quickly enter iptc keywords for each image? It should be keyboard-driven and have autocomplete suggesting previously used keywords.

Answer (score 1):

IPTC maintains a list of [software programs that support IPTC metadata](https://iptc.org/standards/photo-metadata/software-support/?pmd2014=YES). That would be a good place to start in finding the tool that fits your needs. They list:

```
Caption Pro
Cortex Quebec
ExifTool 10.46
Imatch 5.5
Photo Supreme 5.4
Portfolio 2.5.3
STOCKBOX PHOTO 5.40
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to use [Imagga](https://imagga.com) and with sample python program to tag your images. You can register for free and have 2000 API call/images tagged per month. [Here](https://imagga.com/blog/batch-image-processing-from-local-folder-using-imagga-api/) you can find the script

NB! I have no affiliation with above site and service

Comment: Thanks. + for image recognition! I now see I should have specified a preference for local, tin-foil-hat-friendly solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I use VueScan. It is a scanning app that will do everything but change your scanning material. However, it works on Mac, and I am not certain it works on Windows, but you can find out by going to https://www.hamrick.com 
I became aware of them due to the fact that my scanners are older and the mfg's will not upgrade the software to keep up with the OS. So Hamrick keeps everything running for us via this app. It works great and you can enter your own information about your scans. Hope this helps.